# How can I create a multi layer exportable file (.xcf .psd) from multiple raster image in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, clip, multi-band

I have many raster file of the same zone but in differents spectral bands. I would like to create an exportable file of a small portion that can handle different layers. So in practice I would like to implement a sort of **clipper** (Raster->extraction->clipper) with two main features: be able to have multiple file input (maybe with an option: "all the raster in the ROI") and create an output like an .xcf file or .psd file with many layers as the number of raster. How can I do that? I know a little bit of Python can I use the code write for the clipper function?

Comment: I would recommend geospatial PDF, although I am not sure about the abilities of QGIS when it comes to PDFs.